# Map DNS CNAME from subdomain to a path

Tags: cname

Suppose I have a web app running on `myhost.com` with the paths `myhost.com/foo` and `myhost.com/bar`.

Is it possible to use DNS CNAME records to map `foo.myhost.com` to `myhost.com/foo` and `bar.myhost.com` to `myhost.com/bar`.  So for example, the request to `bar.myhost.com/baz` will go to `myhost.com/bar/baz`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with a CNAME, or generally with DNS level configurations, to my knowledge. You'll need a server to redirect or replace the URL location with your desired URL location.

This is possible with a CNAME: foo.myhost.com => bar.yourhost.net

But this is not: foo.myhost.com => bar.myhost.com/foo